# get current prompt number in ipython

Tags: ipython

In `ipython`, by default the input and output prompts are numbered, such as:

```
In [23]:
```

Where is the value (i.e. `23`) stored? Is there a way to get the value of the current prompt number into variable?

```
n = some.function()
print 'current input number is %s' % n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the current number :

```
In [59]: print 'current input number is %s' %(len(In)-1)
current input number is 59
```

`-1` otherwise it's the number of the next not-yet-used input

because :

```
In [60]: print In[59]
print 'current input number is %s' %(len(In)-1)
```

`In` and `Out` are list and dict respectively you can access.

More info here : [input caching system](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html?highlight=prompt#input-caching-system)